# Using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab() from DevTools console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, html2canvas, webpage-screenshot

I'm curious as to whether it is possible to take a screenshot directly from Chrome's DevTools using chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab (be it from the console or from within a snippet), without going through the process of creating an extension.

Is this somehow possible? If not, how would you suggest going about taking a screenshot that reliably mimics the current page (html2canvas doesn't seem to render everything properly). Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a [page screenshot tool](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/screen-capture-by-google/cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg) provided by Google. After installed, you may open "chrome-extension://cpngackimfmofbokmjmljamhdncknpmg/js/page_context.js" in browser to see its code. This extension do not use Chrome Extension API. It works well in most pages, except some complicated pages.

Comment: How would I go about using the code inside page_context.js?

Comment: I'm sorry that I didn't test it recently. This extension use NPAPI, which is not supported by Chrome from Jan 2014. I have found another extension snagit(https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/techsmith-snagit-extensio/annopcfmbiofommjmcmcfmhklhgbhkce), but it uses API for Chrome App.